# WebSocket falla cuando se usa reverse proxy en un servidor Nginx - Error 404

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, websocket

He estado tratando de configurar un servicio de .net 5 ( aspnet core) cuando intento subir el servicio usando como reverse proxy Nginx las peticiones GET y POST funcionan pero las peticiones de tipo wss (WebSocket) fallan.

Tengo la siguiente configuración en el archivo de configuración de nginx:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:5001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Tienen alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Me ha servido ese  archivo de configuración, pero el dotnet está corriendo con http y no con https. hay alguna sugerencia?

Comment: En mi caso yo uso http y https: proxy_pass https://localhost:5000:https://localhost:5001; eso es una moeda de doble filo, internamente cuando el server hace la petición se queda en loopback y no viaja a Internet, no es muy buena práctica, pero es válido.

Comment: Me funcionó el reverse proxy sobre ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes intentar con esto:

Agrega este bloque:

```
upstream websocket {
    server localhost:5000;
}
```

y usa esta expresión regular para que el websocket el cual realmente viaja sobre http/https con la funcionalidad activa de always-connected

```
location /subTextoWSUrl/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        }
```

por ejemplo:
**wss://**miserver.com/**subTextoWSUrl**/a/b/c/d.ejemplo.

Este es mi archivo de configuración:

```
server {

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name miserver.com.co www.miserver.com.co;

        client_max_body_size 100M;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /subTextoWSUrl/ {

                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/miserver.com.co/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/miserver.com.co/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
    if ($host = miserver.com.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = www.miserver.com.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name miserver.com.co www.miserver.com.co;
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: Este bloque : client_max_body_size 100M;
permite subir el límite